# npm registry set without https is not working

Tags: node.js, npm

`npm config list` returns:

```
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false
```

`npm config ls -l global` returns:

```
; registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/" (overridden)
; strict-ssl = true (overridden)
```

so I think my env is setup ok - I am trying to install node/npm in my own space so I can do everything w/o admin. With the setup above, I still get:

```
> npm install -g sql-cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\me\\Projects\\localfs\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\me\\Projects\\localfs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "sql-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
```

adding `--without-ssl` to the command line has no effect. What am I missing? Where are all the global variables that `ls -l global` returns actually set?

No, I can't setup ssl here (these problems do not exist at home in win10/linux/osx)...

Edit: for what it's worth in a linux vm guest on this machine the setup above works fine.

@robertklep: Yes. Same exact behavior in powershell and conemu. npm is totally ignoring its environment is seems.

```
me@this C:\Users\me\Projects\bootstrap-3.3.7
> set | grep NODE
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
> npm install --save
[  ................] \ fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-csslint
// 2-3 minutes pass
[   ...............] \ fetchMetadata: sill fetchPackageMetaData Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Comment: AFAIK, the NPM repository is accessible over HTTPS only. See this blog post (from over a year ago): http://blog.npmjs.org/post/142077474335/npm-registry-is-now-fully-https However, you may be able to get around the TLS error using one of the solutions mentioned here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3742

Comment: This was working just dandy (as admin) until today when I upgraded to node v6.10.3 and tried to clean up my environment a bit. I will check the links... Edit: been through all of that setup (see above, my setup is correct). Will see if I can get hold our our corporate cert (read: not bloody likely).

Comment: @robertklep : note above that setting the http registry and setting strict-ssl to false works like a charm in linux so the repo is definitely available via http. Just tried it again.

Comment: In the blogpost it's stated that HTTP requests get redirected to HTTPS (which might happen under the hood, so it may _look_ like you're connecting to HTTP). Have you tried setting the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` environment variable? (mentioned [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3742#issuecomment-155638113))

Comment: Yes, See above (too much for a comment) in edited post.

Comment: Try setting `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=1`

Comment: Actually in powershell it does seem to try the http connection but it just sits and spins forever...

`PS C:\Users\me\Projects\bootstrap-3.3.7> npm install

[  ................] - fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-csslint

`

Comment: @robertklep: heh guess I should have tried that... Still, same issue - conemu reaches out to the https site (and it fails), powershell reaches out to the http site but just sits and spins forever. As an addedd fact everything works just fine when I bring this laptop home (with easy access to https).

Comment: It sounds like a misbehaving proxy or antivirus software or something, although I would have expected that the Linux VM that you mention would suffer from the same issues in that case.

Comment: It worked fine til I upgraded from Node 6.9 to 6.10. Something in the npm environment got broken. On the github issue I'm tracking I updated npm last night, and it issued a warning about .config:

`npm update check failed │
│ Try running with sudo or get access │
│ to the local update config store via │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\me\Projects\.config|`